# How to remove NaN-s from HTML representation of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, nan

I do the following way

```
table.fillna('')
table.to_html('table.html')
```

and it draws a table, full fo `NaN`-s

How to force it to display spaces?

Comment: fillna doesn't assign inplace, you need table.fillna('', inplace = True)

Comment: I had a similar need. Here's what I did.
`import numpy as np` 
`table = table.replace([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf], '0.0', regex=True)`
Of course you'll want to replace the `0.0` with whatever suits your need.